# How to check role in a voter with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I check Role in voter with Symfony?

I tried to use the following

```
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

To do this I need to inject the `security.context` service, which will trigger a circular reference.

- Should I inject the container which is said to be a bad practice?
- Should I do `$user->getRoles()` and check if the role 'ROLE_ADMIN' is
  owned by $user?
- How can I manage the hierarchy then and inheritance of Role?

Comment: Which exact version do you have? From 2.6 onward, `security.context` has been split into 2 separate services in order to prevent some circular reference issues. You can read about it here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Comment: I have 2.3 version... but I don't think it changes the issue of circular reference with voters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to inject RoleHierarchyInterface and go with point number 3 then.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the `AccessDecisionManagerInterface`:

```
class UserCheckerSomething
{
    private $decisionManager;

    public function __construct(AccessDecisionManagerInterface $decisionManager)
    {
        $this->decisionManager = $decisionManager;
    }

    public function checkAccess(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $this->decisionManager->decide($token, ["ROLE_ADMIN"]);
    }
}
```

And inject the `"@security.access.decision_manager"` into the service :)